# ComboBox Defaulting to all Options Highlighted

Tags: c#, winforms, metroframework

I have a combobox on a c# winform that is not databound (static list of values). When I initially launch the program all options are highlighted. I've disabled all my events for this comboBox and still have this issue. If I select a value it selects fine and will save to a variable but each time I expand the list all values are highlighted. Using MetroFramework library. Thoughts?

[image: comboBox]

[designer.cs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OU1cS.png)

Comment: Is this the `ComboBox` for `WinForms` or are you using another library? I can't recreate this issue myself; tried binding to a `List<string>` as well as just loading items into the `ComboBox` and can't replicate this behavior.

Comment: On another note, I assume the `DropDownStyle` is set to `DropDown`, can you confirm this?

Comment: @Çöđěxěŕ Sorry. Yes. Using MetroFramework. I can add a new ComboBox of the same library to the form and it performs as expected. I've commented out everywhere "cbo_Carrier" is referenced in my Form1.cs and still have the issue. Sorry, I'm still a "baby developer". I attached a screenshot to my original post of Form1.Designer.cs

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, it's important to include these details in your post so we can better assist you. At first look, I knew it didn't look like the standard `WinForm` version. Did you get this library VIA NuGet by chance?

Comment: Looking at https://github.com/thielj/MetroFramework/blob/master/MetroFramework/Controls/MetroComboBox.cs that link, it seems that code is in the `OnDrawItem` unfortunately, I am not seeing a way to change this behavior other than change the theme iteself.

Comment: Are you using `MetroFramework` *OR* `MahApps`, they are completely different from one another.

Comment: Thanks. Yes I got the library via NuGet. Its just interesting that there is different behavior between my existing object and the new object.

Comment: I'm using MetroFramework

Comment: OK, I tagged the correct tag for it, but you changed it back to `MahApps`, that is wrong then.

Comment: lol. "I" didn't. Guess when I edited the post it tried to "help"